# Установка Firebird на Linux с оф сайта

Tags: firebird, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как установить Firebird с оф сайта на Linux Ubuntu Server, а не из репозитария? Скачал архив с установочником, запускаю, пишет задайте новый пароль для SYSDBA, ввожу, и снова просит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А смысл?
Из репозитория Вашей ОСи вы получаете сконфигурированную версию ПО именно под Вашу ОСь.С оф сайта - необходимо скачать, скомпилировать, и только потом устанавливать - не вижу смысла в этой трудозатратности.
А по теме:
1) необходимо скачать devel-пакеты Вашего ядра (без них невозможно скомпилировать ни одну программу);
2) скачать исходники требующейся программы;
2.1) - **ОЧЕНЬ** внимательно прочитать доку по программе (обычно файл install);
3) скомпилировать (осуществить сборку) программы;
4) установить ее из полученных пакетов.
Вот как-то так. В тонкостях - вес описано в интернете. Простой запрос: сборка программы из исходников

Comment: На оф сайте версия новей

Comment: Ну и что? Не все новое - лучшее...  Там может еще в статусе beta2...